# Implement a custom ListView in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I've created a listView in my MainActivity and another layout file for the row layout which looks like this:

[image: my row_layout]

The problem is, how do I implement it? Where do I set all the Strings that have to go in *text*? Where the ones that go in *note*?

I've looked on the internet but I could find someone who had a similar listView as mine.

I know that for Strings I can use arrays, but can I set up an array of ImageViews too?

I'd really appreciate if you could provide me with a detailed answer in which you explain me how to "put things" inside my listView

**EDIT:** added row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/note"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:text="note note note"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans_serif_medium"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: have you ever use getview for listView Or gridView?

Comment: @janki no, this is the first time I'm using a listView

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create

1. a class, (lets name it `DataModel.java`, you can give any name of your wish ) representing your data : `String text, note, image url;` along with getter and setter methods.
2. a class extending `ArrayAdapter`. Override the `getView()` method. Pass the `ArrayList< DataModel >` to the custom array adapter created. Create a constructor and call super to call the constructor of ArrayAdapter ": `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)`.

In the getView method inflate the row layout and set the data [ match the index from the Arraylist with the position parameter of the getView method ]

In the context of your question, I recommend you to study more about `view holder pattern` and  `RecyclerView`, which will help you understand how things work and how they should be done efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a custom class and have it extend ArrayAdapter or BaseAdapter. In it's constructor you can pass it a String array for the text and images. In the getView method, inflate your custom row:

```
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View yourView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.added_row, parent, false);
```

Then, you can set the values of the row using the arrays you passed to set values:

```
TextView text = (TextView) yourView.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText(text[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use custom adapter approach to load data in custom list view.